# Android-10 DeepLink is not working..., but works below android 10 versions

Tags: deeplink

Android-10 DeepLink is not working..., but works below android 10 versions

```
<activity
                android:name="com.post.rest"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    
                    <data
                        android:scheme="http"
                        android:host="my-post.org"
                        android:pathPrefix="/diet.apk" />
                    <data
                        android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="my-post.org"
                        android:pathPrefix="/diet.apk" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

please help me ...thanks